# Text changes position from desktop screen to mobile screen

Tags: html, css

text (instagram and shop) moves downwards into black area as you can see in the following pictures
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3HXl.jpg

heres the code:

HTML

```
<div id="rightBlock">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://instagram.com/pierrebassene.world" style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-weight: bold; font-family: Helvetica ;font-size: 2vw ;">INSTAGRAM</a>
</div>

<div id="mid">
    <a style="font-family: Helvetica ; font-weight: bold; font-size: 2vw;">SIGN UP </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#rightBlock {
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    left: 45.2%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#mid{
    position: fixed;
    top: 82%;
    left: 47%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I've already tried several methods including absolute and fixed positioning but nothing seems to be working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is almost certainly due to the use of percentage values in the 'top' property (can't confirm without more contextual code). Try instead to re-write/re-structure your code so that you are not using percentage values which will change relative to the devices screen size.
You could try switching to pixel values. EG:

`margin-top: 200px; //replace with desired px value`

Also, it is a good habit to enforce the '*separations of concerns*' concept with your code.
HTML is the markup language which describes the structure and contains the actual contents of the page.  CSS is used for styling the pages content.
I recommend you move all the style attributes into your CSS. This keeps your HTML clean and easier to read/maintain for the future, whilst also making it clear where to modify style changes as all the styles are defined in one place (the CSS stylesheet - and not the CSS stylesheet and/or the HTML style attributes).